# .Net 4: How to reference a dynamic object with property named "return"

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0

I'm retrieving json from a public api and converting it into a dynamic object using JsonFx.

```
JsonFx.Json.JsonReader reader = new JsonFx.Json.JsonReader();
dynamic response = reader.Read(jsonAsString);
```

The json contains a property named return. e.g.

```
{"result":"success","return":{"high":{"value":"3.85001","value_int":"385001","display":"3.85001\u00a0\u20ac","currency":"EUR"}}
```

JsonFx creates the dynamic object fine and I can also debug into it and see the values. 
The problem is when I try to reference the property in my code the compiler complains:

```
response.return.high.currency
Identifier expected; 'return' is a keyword
```

How can I reference the return property without the compiler complaining?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `response.@return.high.currency`.

You need to append `@` at the begining of any field wich name is the same as C# keywords.

Comment: Incidentally, the Visual Basic equivalent of using the `@` to escape a keyword in C# is to surround the keyword with square brackets. So you can say "Dim [Next] as String" for example, to declare a variable named Next. Handy to know if you are also using such unusual objects in VB.