# Reading JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, mozilla

I'm trying do a sample application with Mozilla Persona login, but I got an error in a sample code.

**CODE**

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string assertion)
    {
        if (assertion == null)
        {
            // The 'assertion' key of the API wasn't POSTED. Redirect,
            // or whatever you'd like, to try again.
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        using (var web = new WebClient())
        {
            // Build the data we're going to POST.
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["assertion"] = assertion;
            data["audience"] = "https://example.com:443"; // Use your website's URL here.


            // POST the data to the Persona provider (in this case Mozilla)
            var response = web.UploadValues("https://verifier.login.persona.org/verify", "POST", data);
            var buffer = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), Encoding.UTF8, response);


            // Convert the response to JSON.
            var tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, response.Length);
            var reader = new JsonReader();
            dynamic output = reader.Read(tempString);

            if (output.status == "okay")
            {
                string email = output.email; // Since this is dynamic, convert it to string.
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            // Could not log in, do something else.
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

I got a error in the line below, that inform that the constructor cannot take 0 arguments. OK, this is very clear. But this code I got from [Mozilla Persona](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Persona/Quick_Setup).

```
var reader = new JsonReader();
```

**UPDATE**

I got the same error with the code below

```
var reader = new JsonFx.Json.JsonReader();
```

Someone can help me ?

I found some question in stackoverflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579248/net-4-how-to-reference-a-dynamic-object-with-property-named-return) that you can see the same piece of code.

Comment: Read the [MSDN Docs on JSONReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.jsonreader.jsonreader.aspx). The constructor takes two args.

Comment: Yes, but his is my first application integrating this with C#, so I follow the sample in the Mozilla website, but it seems wrong in this line.

Comment: The sample uses the JsonFX JsonReader and it does have a default constructor. What exactly is the error you're getting. This is the actual AuthController source: https://github.com/sergiotapia/ASP.Net-MVC3-Persona-Demo/blob/master/MVC3PersonaDemo/Controllers/AuthController.cs

Comment: The error is: 'JsonFx.Json.JsonReader' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a more recent version of JsonFX, which you can get here: https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx.

In this more recent version, `JsonReader` does in fact contain a default constructor, which should enable your code to work.

In the version you probably have (I found the older version [here](http://www.jsonfx.net/)), `JsonReader` has a number of constructors but none of them accept zero arguments.